# Half dotted half solid line in Epilog LineLegend

Tags: plotting, legending, graphics

I have a plot in which a function is plotted as dotted line in some domain and solid in another, like this:

```
function=Plot[{Piecewise[{{x+10,x<0}},None],Piecewise[{{x+10,x>=0}},None]},{x,-9,9},PlotStyle->{Dotted,Black}]
```

Since I'm plotting multiple functions at the same time I'm using Show and Epilog. For this particular function, I would like the line in the legend to be half dotted and half solid as well (rather than just dotted as below):

```
Show[function, 
Epilog->Inset[Framed[Column[{LineLegend[Thread[Directive[{Black},{Dotted}]],{Style["Function",Medium]},LegendMargins->7]}],RoundingRadius->1],{-5,15.5},{0,0},50]]
```

How can I can make this happen?

*Edit:*

*Screenshot 1*

[image]

*Screenshot 2*
[image]

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work. I will ask the community to please verify it as I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbcOR.png) on my machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
plot1 = Plot[{Piecewise[{{x + 10, x < 0}}, None], 
    Piecewise[{{x + 10, x >= 0}}, None]}, {x, -9, 9}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Dotted, Red}];
plot2 = Plot[4 Sin[x], {x, -5, 6}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, 
   Mesh -> {{4}}, MeshShading -> {Directive[Dashed, Blue], Green}];
plot = Show[plot1, plot2, PlotRange -> All];
markers1 = 
 Graphics[{{Dotted, Line[{{0, 0}, {.5, 0}}]}, {Thick, Red, 
    Line[{{.5, 0}, {1, 0}}]}}];
markers2 = 
 Graphics[{{Dashed, Blue, Line[{{0, 0}, {.8, 0}}]}, {Thick, Green, 
    Line[{{.8, 0}, {1, 0}}]}}];

Legended[plot, 
 Placed[SwatchLegend[{Opacity[1], Opacity[1]}, {Function1, Function2},
    LegendMarkers -> {markers1, markers2}, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 20}, 
   LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 4, 
       FrameStyle -> Brown] &)], {.2, .8}]]
```

[image]

**Original**

```
plot = Plot[{Piecewise[{{x + 10, x < 0}}, None], 
    Piecewise[{{x + 10, x >= 0}}, None]}, {x, -9, 9}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Dotted, Red}];

markers = 
  Graphics[{{Blue, Dotted, Line[{{0, 0}, {.5, 0}}]}, {Thick, Red, 
     Line[{{.5, 0}, {1, 0}}]}}];
Legended[plot, 
 Placed[SwatchLegend[{Opacity[1]}, {Function}, 
   LegendMarkers -> markers, LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 20}, 
   LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 4, 
       FrameStyle -> Brown] &)], {.2, .8}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works, but how can I make it work within Epilog's LineLegend? As I mentioned above I'm using Show and Epilog to create a plot with multiple graphs/functions, but it seems that Graphics does not work in Epilog's LineLegend, see screenshot 2 above.

Comment: `Epilog`,`Inset`,`Framed`,`Show` is not the good way to add Legend, we just need to use `Legended` function to do all this thing.

Comment: OK. How can I use Legended to plot multiple functions? I have looked at the documentation but that does not seem to be its intended use.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. This works great!

Answer (score 4):

```
Show[function, Epilog -> Inset[Framed[
    LineLegend[
     {Directive[Black, 
       Dashing[ConstantArray[0.004, 12]~Join ~
         ConstantArray[0.06, 1]]]}, {Text@
       Style["Function", Medium, 18, FontFamily -> "Euclid Fraktur"]}
     , LegendMargins -> 7
     ]
    , RoundingRadius -> 3
    ]
   , {-5, 15.5}, {0, 0}, 50]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me, see screenshot 1 attached to the original post.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbcOR.png

Comment: Any ideas on what the issue might be on my end?

Comment: Use a font like "Times New Roman" or something that is available on your system. It can't be that but let's rule it out.

Comment: OK, done! Unfortunately this didn't fix the problem, but as you said at least we can rule it out now.

Comment: I am on v12.2.0 Win7-x64.

Comment: @Syed not sure what version the author of the OP has, but in `v12` does not work either https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yPco.png

Comment: I'm also on v12.0.0.